# parsing a classname with Reg-Exp

Tags: java

I have some troubles with reg exp. I want to check if a class name is "good".
I want to parse these with reg exp.

```
if(ClassClass1
theresNoClass
```

I tried this:

```
[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+
```

But it also said `atheresNoClass` is a good name, so I decided to check if any letters are on the left:

```
[^a-z][A-Z][a-zA-Z]+
```

But the '(' got through, I don't need it.

**Good examples of class names:**

- Graphics2D
- SomeClass
- System

**Bad examples:**

- if(Class
- (SomeClass
- noFunction

Comment: Give example of right and wrong input ;) start with Uppercase ?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking but in any case you should review a good tutorial on regular expressions.

Comment: Don't add things in comment : EDIT your POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only thing you're missing here is to match the word boundaries.

In regex `\b` matches a word boundary. The problem you are having now is that it matches everything that starts with a uppercase character (`NoClass` for example) even if it is inside a word.

By adding `\b` to the end of start of your regex, you will only find matches that are whole words:

```
\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+\b
```

Comment: only in 4 minutes, i know

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+` and you need to make sure you have not switched on the case-insensitive flag.

Answer (score 0):

As you only requirement is "have an Uppercase lettre at beginning"

So you should use : `^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+`

- `^` says that it must be start of the tex
- `[A-Z]` says uppercase letter
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` says one or more of a letter or digit (\w has '_' also and not good)

With this structure `^[A-Z]` you are sure that there will be no other things that uppercase letter at the beginning, as you asked

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/jhBDve/1)